# Error in DotNetNuke slides container

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I'm new to DNN so I would really appreciate your help.
I took the following DNN theme "[DNN capastrano theme](http://dnntheme.com/capastrano/Home)"
and acheived my website using it. After I finsihed everything I wa trying something ith the slides container on top of home page, its style changed and it shows no pix, so "clever me" I started to edit its content using the original website code for this container, but it is not working at all.
And I don't have the very first version anymore. What should I do ??

And this is the last code I wrote for it:

```
 <div class="DnnModule DnnModule-DNN_HTML DnnModule-369"><a name="369"></a>
<div class="DNNContainer_noTitle">
<div id="dnn_ctr369_ContentPane"><!-- Start_Module_369 -->
<div id="dnn_ctr369_ModuleContent" class="DNNModuleContent ModDNNHTMLC">
<div id="dnn_ctr369_HtmlModule_lblContent" class="Normal">
<div id="container">
<div id="example">
<div id="slides">
<div class="slides_container" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block;">
<div class="slides_control" style="position: relative; width: 2940px; height: 380px; left: -980px;"><a title="banner 1" href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 980px; z-index: 0; display: none;"><img width="980" height="380" alt="Slide 1" src="/portals/0/Images/Banner1.jpg?1382021639165" /></a><a title="banner 2" href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 980px; z-index: 0; display: none;"><img width="980" height="380" alt="Slide 2" src="/portals/0/Images/Banner2.jpg" /></a><a title="banner 3" href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 980px; z-index: 5; display: block;"><img width="980" height="380" alt="Slide 3" src="/portals/0/Images/Banner3.jpg" /></a><a title="banner 4" href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 980px; z-index: 0; display: none;"><img width="980" height="380" alt="Slide 4" src="/portals/0/Images/Banner4.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>
<div class="pagination_wrap">
<a class="prev" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
<a class="next" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End_Module_369 --></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off hand you are copying too much into your HTML module :

I would think that this is the content for that (by default) - not pretty below but if that does not work then take out the wrapping

```
 <div id="container">
<div id="example">
<div id="slides">
<div class="slides_container" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block;">
<div class="slides_control" style="position: relative; width: 2940px; height: 380px; left: -980px;"><a title="banner 1" href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 980px; z-index: 0; display: none;"><img width="980" height="380" alt="Slide 1" src="/capastrano/portals/0/Images/Banner1.jpg?1382628851302"></a><a title="banner 2" href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 980px; z-index: 5; display: block;"><img width="980" height="380" alt="Slide 2" src="/capastrano/portals/0/Images/Banner2.jpg"></a><a title="banner 3" href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 980px; z-index: 0; display: none;"><img width="980" height="380" alt="Slide 3" src="/capastrano/portals/0/Images/Banner3.jpg"></a><a title="banner 4" href="#" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 980px; z-index: 0; display: none;"><img width="980" height="380" alt="Slide 4" src="/capastrano/portals/0/Images/Banner4.jpg"></a></div>



</div>
<div class="pagination_wrap">
<a class="prev" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
<a class="next" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<ul class="pagination"><li class=""><a href="#0">1</a></li><li class="current"><a href="#1">2</a></li><li class=""><a href="#2">3</a></li><li class=""><a href="#3">4</a></li></ul></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```